# How to extract filenames with two file extensions?

Tags: python, filepath, os.path, dirname

I have a folder containing multiple files which have the double extension *".nii.gz"*. I want to extract the filenames using `os.path.basename` but this function returns the filenames only with the first extension *".nii"*. How can I extract the full filenames with both extensions?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the good old `str.split`

```
filename = 'file.nil.gz'
li = filename.split('.')
basename = li[0]
extensions = li[1:]

print(basename)
#file
print(extensions)
#['nil', 'gz']
```

Answer (score 0):

This function extracts the entire name, even with multiple ".":

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = 'blabla'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
print(onlyfiles)
```

if you don't want to see the extention, then here is the add-on:

```
onlyfiles = [f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
print(onlyfiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, best practice is to use `pathlib` for operations with file path.

Code:

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path("C://filename.tar.gz").suffixes)
```

Result:

```
['.tar', '.gz']
```

To extract all suffixes into one string just join them:

```
print("".join(Path("C://filename.tar.gz").suffixes))
```

Comment: OP wants to extract filenames NOT suffixes

Comment: @ruslaniv, so he got an answer, what do you want from me?